# Does Delphi provide access to the Android Auth.GoogleSignInApi class?

Tags: java, android, delphi, firemonkey, google-signin

More specifically, is it possible to translate this Java code, which retrieves a ID token, to Delphi?

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
if (result.isSuccess()) {
    GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
    String idToken = acct.getIdToken();
    mIdTokenTextView.setText("ID Token: " + idToken);
    // TODO(user): send token to server and validate server-side
} else {
    mIdTokenTextView.setText("ID Token: null");
}
```

I could not find a wrapper class in the Delphi Docwiki, or a feature request in the quality portal.

Comment: It is possible to translate any Java for Android code to Delphi for Android. It is however mostly not a trivial exercise. Not sure I'm up for that right now to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which library you need to use in your particular case or if it's already [included](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Using_the_Built-in_RAD_Studio_Java_Libraries_for_Android) in Delphi but using the supplied [Java2OP](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Java2OP.exe,_the_Native_Bridge_File_Generator_for_Android) tool, it should be possible to generate Delphi wrapper units to [use any custom Java library](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Using_a_Custom_Set_of_Java_Libraries_In_Your_RAD_Studio_Android_Apps).